# NHibernate Many To Many reference help

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have 2 tables (entities) like the following

```
NewsLetter
-------------------
Id
UserEmail
AgreeToReceiveNewsLetters
DateRegisted

Voucher
-------------------
Id
Code
IsActive
PromoText
CreatedDate
MaxDaysToRedeem
```

and a third reference table for many to many relationhip

```
NewsLetterVoucher
-------------------
Id
NewsLetter_id
Voucher_id
ValidFrom
ValidUntil
DateRedeemed
DateNotified
```

All is working good the the mappings for the many to many relationship working good
The problem is that I want to have access in the entity model at the additional information that are stored in the reference table (ValidFrom , ValidUntil etc)

just like

> NewsLetter.Voucher[0].ValidFrom

but ValidFrom is stored in the refenece table

How I can do that

Comment: I think both Circadian and Stefan have what you are looking for below.  You really need two one to many relationships here.  One from NewsLetter and one from Voucher to a 3rd class called NewsLetterVoucher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar question ([NHibernate: Many-to-many relationship with field in the relationship table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713329/nhibernate-many-to-many-relationship-with-field-in-the-relationship-table/2713384#2713384)). You need to map the relation table as a class.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a solution to your problem, if I understand it correctly.

[fluent nhibernate - Many to Many mapping with attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028172/fluent-nhibernate-many-to-many-mapping-with-attribute)