# Many To Many Mapping with Attribute - Primary key is Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am having trouble mapping my many to many with a attribute relationship. Much like the problem here

[fluent nhibernate - Many to Many mapping with attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028172/fluent-nhibernate-many-to-many-mapping-with-attribute)

But I do not have a Primary Key on my middle class, instead it is made up of the IDs of the other two classes.

Quotation SKU Class (middle Class)

```
public class QuotationSKUCost : Entity
{
    public virtual decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public virtual Quotation Quotation { get; set; }
    public virtual QuotationRequestSKU QuotationRequestSKU { get; set; }
}
```

Quotation Class

```
public class Quotation : Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; } 
    public virtual DateTime ValidUntil { get; set; }
    public virtual string Data { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<QuotationSKUCost> QuotationSKUCosts { get; set; }
}
```

Quotation Request SKU

```
public class QuotationRequestSKU : Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int Quantity { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<QuotationSKUCost> QuotationSKUCost { get; set; }
}
```

Middle Class Mapping!!

```
    public QuotationSKUCostMapping()
    {
        Table("QuotationSKUCost");
        CompositeId() //need to map QuotationId and QuotationRequestSKUid as Composite key
          .KeyProperty(x => x.Quotation, "QuotationId")
          .KeyReference(x => x.QuotationRequestSKU, "QuotationRequestSKUId");
        Map(x => x.UnitPrice);
    }
```

The error I am getting when trying to debug is:

> *Could not determine type for: ORM.Entities.Quote.Quotation, ORM,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, for columns:
>   NHibernate.Mapping.Column(QuotationId)*

*EDIT:* Adding Quotation Mapping

```
    public QuotationMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("QuotationId");
        Map(x => x.ValidUntil);
        Map(x => x.Data);
        HasMany(x => x.QuotationSKUCosts).KeyColumn("QuotationId");
    }
```

Comment: What's the configuration for your `Quotation` class?

Comment: I've added a the quotation mapping

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after much looking

```
          .KeyProperty(x => x.Quotation, "QuotationId")
          .KeyReference(x => x.QuotationRequestSKU, "QuotationRequestSKUId");
```

Should be

```
          .KeyReference(x => x.Quotation, "QuotationId")
          .KeyReference(x => x.QuotationRequestSKU, "QuotationRequestSKUId");
```